Connecting to a specific wallet with Ether.js
I have Metamask and Core Wallet installed on Chrome. I want two buttons for them. When I click on the Metamask button, it'll be connected to Metamask, and when I click the other button, it'll be connected to the Core. But I couldn't find a way to do it.
I can't specify the wallet with window.ethereum.request(). Is there a way to connect a specific wallet with ethers js?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
